# Node js.. create a proxy server which will monitor & log the traffic

Tags: node.js, proxy, capture, traffic

I basically want to set up a proxy server using Node.js which will capture the outgoing requests and the incoming response and dump it in a file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Winston what you need? I use it for my logging, so I know it is very flexible. Perhaps of most interest to you is the Loggly support so you can output logs to another service.

Answer (score 1):

Googling ["node proxy server"](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=node+proxy+server) reveals some modules you could use. There's [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) and [node proxy](https://github.com/csquared/node-proxy).

As for the file dump you would simply need to use [fs](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/fs.html) to open/create and write to the file.